# What fields makes the android keystore unique?

Tags: android, android-keystore

Can I create a new one if I loose the android (APK) keystore file? I know all data e.g. first name, last name, organization,password,expiration etc. Can I create the same keystore using these data or I should protect the main keystore file in a safe place?

Is there something like timestamp or hashed or automatically generated data inside the keystore or those data fields that I wrote manually, make the keystore unique and identifiable?

Comment: you should protect your main keystore file in a safe place

Answer (score 0):

`Keystore` is nothing more than a container. It contain keys, a public-key certificates used for signing your applications prior to deploy them.

> Android requires that all APKs be digitally signed with a certificate before they can be installed. 
>   When you sign an APK, the signing tool attaches the public-key
>   certificate to the APK. The public-key certificate serves as as a
>   "fingerprint" that uniquely associates the APK to you and your
>   corresponding private key. This helps Android ensure that any future
>   updates to your APK are authentic and come from the original author.
>   The key used to create this certificate is called the app signing key.
>
> A keystore is a binary file that contains one or more private keys.

You can create new keystore, and, in case you put there your original certificate, there's no difference. You can extract certificate from one keystore and put it to another one.

Basically, a tool, `Android Studio` or `keytool` for example, generate those keys for you and put them into keystore. Physically, keys are `RSA keypair`, like this example http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/examples.html, private key used for signing and stored in your keystore **only**, public key used for checking of signature.

There is no possibility to recover key if you lost your keystore.
So, **do your absolute best to protect the keystore**, especially if you have published apps signed by it's certificates.

Comment: `A keystore is a binary file that contains one or more private keys.` . What are those private keys? automatically generated keys or the manual data field that I wrote there?

Comment: A tool, `Android Studio` or `keytool` for example, generate those keys for you and put them into keystore. Physically, keys are `RSA keypair`, like this http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/examples.html.

Comment: When you sign you app, it calculates the hash of it using private key, and store the hash and public key in the `apk` file. `Google Play store` will save public key and use it for further checks of new versions of your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you have released your application on play store then it will not let you update your app because now you have a different keystore file and hence you have to create new app on playstore. Yes every keystore file is unique and you won't be able to make the same again

Answer (score 0):

For **KeyStore** i can say that
 Keystore is unique. no one but the holder of your certificate can update your application. That means that if you release it into the wild, lose the cert you used to sign the application, then you cannot release updates so keep that cert safe and backed up if need be.

But apart from signing apks to release into the wild, you can use it to authenticate your device to a server over SSL if you so desire, (also Android related) among other functions.

I have faced same thing and from my experience i can say nothing is going to work may be i am wrong there may be some ways but i tried lot..

> You can create a new keystore, but the Android Market wont allow you
>   to upload the apk as an update - worse still, if you try uploading the
>   apk as a new app it will not allow it either as it knows there is a
>   'different' version of the same apk already in the market even if you
>   delete your previous version from the market

*Do your absolute best to find that keystore...*

Answer (score 0):

Google suggested 1 way to upload your keystore securely so no need to worry about keystore anymore.

For more details check:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#google-play-app-signing

Answer (score 0):

No you cant. There is no way create same .keystore file with same password and alias. IF you lost your key file, you can reset your file from google play.

You can follow the steps below;

1. create a new keystore file
2. Generate a pem file from this keystore file
3. Use the command for this.
4. "keytool -export -rfc -alias your alias -file your alias_certificate.pem -keystore you keystore name.jks"
5. Fill out the form below and add the pem file to the form. ;
   https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs?hl=en